# SQL Server: join 2 tables with condition ON statement

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  I have a query in which I'm doing a LEFT JOIN between 2 tables to see which rows in table A are not in table B.  The basic query is:

```
SELECT
A.a_col,
B.b_col
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.some_key = B.another_key
WHERE
B.another_key IS NULL
```

I need to do run this same query again when any rows return from the given query.  However, I don't want any rows from the above query to output if the second query runs.  In the second instance, I need to transform A.some_key a bit as follows:

```
SELECT
A.a_col,
B.b_col
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON '0' + A.some_key = B.another_key
WHERE
B.another_key IS NULL
```

I need both steps in one SQL batch (group of statements).  In other words, if any rows return from the first query, then the second query executes, and the final result set comes only from this second query, not the first.  How do I achieve this?

Comment: would you want data from the second query if row return for the first but they would exist for the second?

Comment: Yes.  Essentially, I'm trying to see if A.some_key is in table B.  If it's not found on just some_key, then I need to see if it's found on '0' + some_key.

Comment: So if you can have both in the results, a Union statement is the simplest way to go.

Comment: You state: "if no rows return from the first query, then the second query executes". What happens if first query returns some rows? What is the ouput in this case?

Comment: That should have read "if [any] rows return from the first query, then the second query executes".  Sorry about that.

Comment: Ok, what happens then if *no* rows return from the first query? What is the result in this case? No rows at all?

Comment: If no rows return from the first query, then do not execute the second query.

Comment: Are these queries to be executed inside a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If first query of the OP returns *any* rows, then the following query will return all rows from second query of the OP. Otherwise, no rows are returned.

```
SELECT A.a_col, B.b_col
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON '0' + A.some_key = B.another_key
WHERE B.another_key IS NULL AND 
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM A
              LEFT JOIN B ON A.some_key = B.another_key
              WHERE B.another_key IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem correctly, but you can use

UNION

```
SELECT A.a_col, B.b_col
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.some_key = B.another_key
UNION
SELECT A.a_col, B.b_col
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON '0' + A.some_key = B.another_key
```

OR

```
SELECT A.a_col, B.b_col
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON 
    (A.some_key = B.another_key) 
OR  ('0' + A.some_key = B.another_key)
```

If you only need the second query to be executed if the first doesn't return any results, you can try this....

```
SELECT A.a_col, B.b_col
FROM A
    JOIN B ON A.some_key = B.another_key
UNION
SELECT A.a_col, B.b_col
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON '0' + A.some_key = B.another_key
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM A
    JOIN B ON A.some_key = B.another_key) = 0
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I can't use a UNION or an OR.  I think I need to be more clear.  The problem is that I don't want to see the result set from the first query if the second query needs to execute (which only executes when the first query does return anything).  This is for data validation.

Comment: The problem is the LEFT JOIN. That will cause the 1st query to ALWAYS return any rows in A. If you change the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN, they 3rd query in my answer should work

Comment: I can't change the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN.  My first query actually returns all rows in A that are not in B.  In other words, the first query's basic form is SELECT A.a_col, B.b_col FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.some_key = B.another_key WHERE B.another_key IS NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into the specifics of code, I would wrap the first select as an INSERT into a temp table, then using @@rowcount to see if there were some actual rows selected you can execute the second query which would therefore ignore the insert into the temp table, and your query would only return one dataset.